# Excel formula- If value is greater than.. move to next cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm pretty new to formula's- what I would like is a formula that **IF** the value in E24 is greater than 150 then the F24 would equal 150 and the offset in G24 would be the remainder.

So for example if E24 was 200, F24 would be 150 and G24 would be 50.

I've played around and this is what I have so far.

```
=IF(E24 > 150,G24=E24-150,E24)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a different cell value from a formula, so will need another formula in G24 also.

In F24 put `=IF(E24>150, 150, "")` and in G24 `=IF(E24>150, E24-F24, "")`

Comment: Great thanks, but is there a way also so lets say G24 overspills, for H to have the remainder all the way up to Z?

Comment: Probably, what condition causes overspilling?

Answer (score 1):

in F24 put `=IF(E24>150,150,E24)`
in G24 put `=IF(E24>F24,E24-F24,0)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I download my various accounts to Excel and wanted to avoid manual copying line by line.  I couldn't make the formulae above work, so I dumbed them down to my level.  this works fine:

```
in E6   =IF($D6>0,D6,"")
in F6   =IF($D6<0,D6,"")
```

then I format the columns to Currency